# ¿Cómo añadir imagen en navbar? bootstrap 3 (sin usarla como logo)

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap, css3, imagen

Sucede que quiero agregar una miniatura de perfil a una lado de un dropdown navbar en bootstrap. Ya he intentado agragarla como imagen pero solo funciona si cambio su tamaño a 20px*20px, Necesito que sea 40px*40px sin alterar el tamaño del navbar

[image: Navbar sin imagen de perfil]

El efecto que quiero lograr es parecido al de twitter incluso con el border radius.

[image: Twitter]

```css
/*MODIFICA EL NAVBAR*/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: none;
  /* border-color: #dfdfdf; */
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  /*
    aquí se modifica el hover del brand
  */
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li.divider {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #38397f;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #5355bf;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #38397f;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #38397f;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
  }
}


/*MODIFICA LOS BADGES*/

.badge {
  background-color: #5355bf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/463aacdde3.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>LaKill - Inicio</title>
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true">
          &nbsp;
        </i>
          <!-- <img alt="Brand" src="..."> Poner imagen del logo-->
          LOGO
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#" class="efectito"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>ENLACE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="efectito"><i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>ENLACE</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><span class="badge">4</span></a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">

            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle negrita" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Crixodia
          </a>
            <!-- <span class="caret"></span> Agrega un indicador de flecha abajo -->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Perfil</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cuenta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Soporte</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno no usado mucho bootstrap 3, pero espero que mi código te ayude.

```css
/*MODIFICA EL NAVBAR*/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: none;
  /* border-color: #dfdfdf; */
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  /*
    aquí se modifica el hover del brand
  */
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu>li.divider {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #38397f;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #5355bf;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #38397f;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #5355bf;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #38397f;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #38397f;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
  }
}


/*MODIFICA LOS BADGES*/

.badge {
  background-color: #5355bf;
}

/* Encuadrando imagen a 40px */
.navbar-brand{
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/463aacdde3.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>LaKill - Inicio</title>
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true">
          &nbsp;
        </i>
         <img alt="Brand" src="https://cdn6.aptoide.com/imgs/f/e/c/fec372f7c957ad5393911379e3a7c2a8_icon.png?w=40">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#" class="efectito"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>ENLACE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="efectito"><i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>ENLACE</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><span class="badge">4</span></a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i><span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">

            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle negrita" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Crixodia
          </a>
            <!-- <span class="caret"></span> Agrega un indicador de flecha abajo -->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Perfil</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cuenta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Soporte</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho :D